# Use of time.sleep() in Python with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a small program (a part of a larger project) to show 10 Random numbers with a small delay.
The function it self works when I run it in a terminal, BUT when I try to show it in Tkinter it only shows the Random numbers but without the time delay??
(If I use the Button a single random number comes up every time?)

---

```
import random, time
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Cirkus Arcus tidsmaskine!")
window.geometry("800x800")

#---FUNCTIONS----

def  random_number():
    counter = 0      
    while counter<10:
        num = random.randint(1000,3000)         
        num10 = int(num / 10) * 10             
        time.sleep(0.2) 
        counter = counter + 1          
        return (num10)
```

## ---DISPLAYS----

```
def number_display2():
    randomNumber = random_number()

    # This creates a text field
    number_display2 = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width=30)
    number_display2.grid(column=0, row=4)
    number_display2.insert(tk.END, randomNumber)
```

## ---BUTTONS----

```
button2 = tk.Button(text="Prøv også mig", command=number_display2)
button2.grid(column=1, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are countless post on `sleep()` and `tkinter` and what you should do instead. Don't use `sleep()` or a `while` statement within the same thread as tkinter. It will block the mainloop until they have completed and you will only ever see the final result.

Comment: Search this site for `[tkinter] sleep is:question` to see literally hundreds of questions about using sleep with tkinter.

Comment: Are you wanting to display each number with a time delay or simple display all 10 numbers at once?

Comment: I want to display each number with a time delay.

Answer (score 1):

The using of time.sleep() blocks the program.

The definition of time.sleep() in the documentation it's :

> Suspend execution of the calling thread for the given number of
>   seconds.

If you want to delay in Tkinter you can use the after() method,

> .after(delay, callback=None) is a method defined for all tkinter
>   widgets. This method simply calls the function callback after the
>   given delay in ms. If no function is given, it acts similar to
>   time.sleep (but in milliseconds instead of seconds)

You have to use :

```
window.after(10000)  # 10000 means 10s
```

Comment: `window.after(10000)` has the same effect as `sleep(10)` - it will block the program.

Comment: Actually you can use time.sleep() with Tkinter but you have to use update() too. Try adding window.update() after  time.sleep(0.2)

Comment: Yes, you can use it but it will lock up the window while it is sleeping.

Comment: It seems that neither of them works. If I add windows.updat() after time.sleep(0.2) it doesn't make any difference. And windows.after(500) just blocks the program and everything stops.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using the "after" method when it comes to Tkinter. There have been several other questions regarding this topic. Please note that the delay is in milliseconds instead of the seconds used in `time.sleep()`

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
root=tk.Tk()
def random_number():
    counter = 0   
    while counter<10:
       num = random.randint(1000,3000)         
       num10 = int(num / 10) * 10             
       print(counter)
       print(num10)
       counter = counter + 1
    return(num10)
root.after(2000,random_number)
root.mainloop()
```

This works but my kernel keeps running after it finishes

Comment: You will also need to get rid of `while` as it also blocks the main loop just like sleep does.

Comment: what would you use to ensure the condition is met? Also, to iterate

Comment: Depends on what the user is actually trying to do. If they want all the values to display at once I would not even use an after statement at all. Simple run a loop to get all 10 values and writer them to the text widget. If they want to display them with some delay then I would use an after statement to run the function 10 times from within the function and then once the count is at 10 simply end the after loop.

Comment: Yeah the "why" or "goal" is foggy, not sure why it was formatted in the original way

Comment: This works fine, but it still only shows the numbers in the terminal via PRINT. But the numbers should show in the display in Tkinter.

Comment: You may have to use the label or text.insert functions that tkinter has in its library to add to the window