# TKINTER GUI freezed after starting the AutoClicker Bot

Tags: python, tkinter, automation, bots

i was making a Auto Clicker Bot and when i am startig the Bot with the selected key, the Bot freezes. (it is still working) I dont know, what i did wrong in my code? (i am new at coding so dont be so ruff to me :^))

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
press = "NO KEY SELECTED"

#ALLE DEFINITIONEN VON COMMANDS
#Clicker
def clicker():
    while True:
        if clicking:
            mouse.click(Button.left, 2)
        time.sleep(0.00001)

#EVENT
def toggle_event(key):
    if key == TOGGLE_KEY:
        global clicking
        clicking = not clicking

#Bot
def bot():
    global TOGGLE_KEY
    global clicking
    global mouse
    print(f"Drücke den Knopf. = '{press}'")
    TOGGLE_KEY = KeyCode(char=press)
    clicking = False
    mouse = Controller()
    click_thread = threading.Thread(target=clicker)
    click_thread.start()
    with Listener(on_press=toggle_event) as listener:
        listener.join()


#ACCEPT BUTTON NACH SETTINGS EINGABE
def settings_entry_accept_def():
    global press
    settings_entry.get()
    press = settings_entry.get().lower()
    settings_entry_accept.place_forget()
    settings_entry.place_forget()
    key_text.place_forget()
    text_settings.place(x=365, y=374)
    text_settings.configure(text="SAVED!", bg="grey5", fg="lightgreen")


#Einblenden von Entryfeld und Accept nach Klicken des Settingsbutton
def settings_button_def():
    settings_entry.place(x=349, y=377)
    settings_entry_accept.place(x=409, y=377)

#main Window einstellungen
main = tk.Tk()
main.geometry("500x400")
main.title("Auto-Clicker by Mork")
main.resizable(False, False)
main.config(bg="grey5")

#Titel
titel_text = tk.Label(main, text="Auto-Clicker",bg="grey5", fg="DARKRED", font=("Arial", 42))
titel_text.place(x=10,y=0)
titel_text_name = tk.Label(main, text="by Mork",bg="grey5", fg="DARKRED", font=("Arial", 26))
titel_text_name.place(x=190,y=70)

#Key to AutoClick
key_text = tk.Label(main, text=press, bg="grey5", fg="DARKRED")
key_text.place(x=345, y=313)

#TEXT UNTER SETTINGS
text_settings = tk.Label(main)

#SELECT KEY Button im Main Window
settings_button = tk.Button(main, text="KEY SELECT", bg="DARKRED", fg="LIGHTGREEN", width=10, height=2, font=("Arial", 10), command=settings_button_def)
settings_button.place(x=349, y=333)

#Entry Feld unter Settins Button
settings_entry = tk.Entry(main, bg="DARKRED", fg="LIGHTGREEN", width=9)


#Haken neben Entry Feld
settings_entry_accept = tk.Button(main, text="✔", bg="DARKRED", fg="LIGHTGREEN", width=4, height=1, command=settings_entry_accept_def)

#Start Button
start_button = tk.Button(main, text="Start Bot", bg="DARKRED", fg="LIGHTGREEN", width=10, height=2,font=("Arial", 10), command=bot)
start_button.place(x=78, y=333)

main.mainloop()
```

I googled many times how to fix that. It is called a "Blocking-version" of pynput. I dont know what that is and how to fix it. I heard about the "time.sleep()" function that it doesnt work on this, but idk what else i can use.

Comment: Try searching SO for `time.sleep` problems in `tkinter`. Here's one to get you started. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413273/use-of-time-sleep-in-python-with-tkinter